# Parsing Karma Coverage Output in Bash for a Jenkins Job (Scripting)

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm working with the following output:

```
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 26.16% ( 1681/6425 )
Branches     : 6.89% ( 119/1727 )
Functions    : 23.82% ( 390/1637 )
Lines        : 26.17% ( 1680/6420 )
================================================================================
```

I would like to parse the 4 coverage percentage numbers without the percent via REGEX, into a comma separated list.

Any suggestions for a good regex expression for this? Or another good option?

Comment: kindly post the expected output too in your post.

Comment: Hi Jeff. These _all_ seem like good answers, except maybe the `bash` one, and people have put work into them. I think the `grep` one is the clearest, better than my `sed`. Anyway, I am voting them all up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a `grep` job. This should help:

```
$ grep -oE "[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{2}" input.txt | xargs | tr " " ","
```

Output:

```
26.16,6.89,23.82,26.17
```

The input file just contains what you have shown above. Obviously, there are other ways like `cat` to feed the input to the command.

Explanation:

- `grep -oE`: only show matches using extended regex
- `xargs`: put all results onto a single line
- `tr " " ","`: translate the spaces into commas:

This is actually a nice shell tool belt example, I would say.

---

Including the consideration of [Joseph Quinsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318716/joseph-quinsey), the regex can be made more robust with a lookahead to assert a `%` sign after then numeric value using a Perl-compatible RE pattern:

```
grep -oP "[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{2}(?=%)" input.txt | xargs | tr " " ","
```

Comment: Maybe you could add a `%` to the end of your RE, to make it more robust, and then remove the `%` with `tr`?

Comment: @JosephQuinsey good idea. I used a PCRE with a lookahead to do so.

Comment: Thank you @wp78de, however it has a bit of trouble when it rounds up to one decimal place - I.E Branches 8.1% ( 140/1729 ), so using "[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}(?=%)" did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Bonus: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51807953/parse-comma-separated-string-of-numbers-into-variables-scripting-bash

Answer (score 3):

The `sed` command:

```
  sed -n '/ .*% /{s/.* \(.*\)% .*/\1/;p;}' input.txt | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g'
```

gives the output:

```
  26.16,6.89,23.82,26.17
```

---

**Edit:** A better answer, with only a single `sed`, would be:

```
  sed -n '/ .*% /{s/.* \(.*\)% .*/\1/;H;};${g;s/\n/,/g;s/,//;p;}' input.txt
```

Explanation:

- `/ .*% /` search for lines with a percentage value (note spaces)
- `s/.* \(.*\)% .*/\1/` and delete everything except the percentage value
- `H` and then append it to the hold space, prefixed with a newline
- `$` then for the last line
- `g` get the hold space
- `s/\n/,/g` replace all the newlines with commas
- `s/,//` and delete the initial comma
- `p` and then finally output the result

To harden the regex, you could replace the search for the percentage value `.*%` with for example `[0-9.]*%`.

Answer (score 2):

Would you consider to use `awk`? Here's the command you may try,

```
$ awk 'match($0,/[0-9.]*%/){s=(s=="")?"":s",";s=s substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)}END{print s}' file
26.16,6.89,23.82,26.17
```

Brief explanation,

- `match($0,/[0-9.]*%/)`: find the record matched with regex `[0-9.]*%`
- `s=(s=="")?"":s","`: since comma separated is required, we just need print commas before each matched except the first one.
- `s=s substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)`: print the matched part appended to `s`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the item names (Statements, Branches, ...) do not contain whitespaces, how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a keys
declare -a vaues

while read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^([^\ ]+)\ *:\ *([0-9.]+)% ]]; then
        keys+=(${BASH_REMATCH[1]})
        values+=(${BASH_REMATCH[2]})
    fi
done < output.txt

ifsback=$IFS        # backup IFS
IFS=,
echo "${keys[*]}"
echo "${values[*]}"
IFS=$ifsback        # restore IFS
```

which yields:

```
Statements,Branches,Functions,Lines
26.16,6.89,23.82,26.17
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yet another option, with perl:**

```
cat the_file | perl -e 'while(<>){/(\d+\.\d+)%/ and $x.="$1,"}chop $x; print $x;'
```

The code, unrolled and explained:

```
while(<>){  # Read line by line. Put lines into $_
  /(\d+\.\d+)%/ and $x.="$1,"
  # Equivalent to:
  # if ($_ =~ /(\d+\.\d+)%/) {$x.="$1,"}
  # The regex matches "numbers", "dot", "numbers" and "%", 
  # stores just numbers on $1 (first capturing group)
}
chop $x; # Remove extra ',' and print result
print $x;
```

**Somewhat shorter with an extra sed**

```
cat the_file | perl -ne '/(\d+\.\d+)%/ and print "$1,"'|sed 's/.$//'
```

Uses "n" parameter which implies `while(<>){}`. For removing the last ',' we use sed.